# How to save data in a cards based database stack?

Tags: livecode, hypercard

I understand that in livecode you may do a database type application a) as a collection of cards as in HyperCard or b) with an SQL db engine like SQLite. In Hypercard (a) there was no need to save data entered into data fields. In livecode I need to use 'File/save' to save data in the development mode. How do I save data in a stand alone application which is cards based. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the "save" command to save the state of your stack in code. To do this in a built standalone however, you need to do a little bit of wrangling by launching the stack with a launcher as detailed in this lesson:

http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/17375-how-do-i-save-custom-properties-in-a-standalone-application

Comment: It works fine. I have a `on closeStack` handler in the script of the stack which contains the data. The handler contains the command 
    `save this stack` and then passes on with `pass closeStack`

Answer (score 1):

The executable is never saved. The usual way LC standalones manage this is to create a "splash" stack, which may have a use or not, be visible or not, and contain useful data. Or not. But it is the executable.

And then as many other stacks, substacks and other resources are attached to that stack file as might be required, and all these can be saved. The reason the executable is called a "splash" is because it might appear as an intro window at startup, only to be dismissed in order to get the real work done.

Craig Newman